# How to list tables/views that depend on a specific table in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Before making changes I need to check downstream dependencies for a given table. How would I go about listing any Redshift tables or views that depend on specific_table?

I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c_p.oid AS tbloid
    ,n_p.nspname AS schemaname
    ,c_p.relname AS NAME
    ,n_c.nspname AS refbyschemaname
    ,c_c.relname AS refbyname
    ,c_c.oid AS viewoid
FROM pg_class c_p
JOIN pg_depend d_p ON c_p.relfilenode = d_p.refobjid
JOIN pg_depend d_c ON d_p.objid = d_c.objid
JOIN pg_class c_c ON d_c.refobjid = c_c.relfilenode
LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n_p ON c_p.relnamespace = n_p.oid
LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n_c ON c_c.relnamespace = n_c.oid
WHERE d_c.deptype = 'i'::"char"
AND c_c.relkind = 'v'::"char"
and schemaname like 'actual_schema_name'
and name = 'actual_table_name';
```

But this was from some basic googling and I really don't know if it's close.

Comment: It should work, bur remember that Redshift is case sensitive

Answer (score 5):

I recommend implementing the [Admin Views from the official Redshift Utils github repository](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/tree/master/src/AdminViews) from the AWS Redshift team, this will give you a heap of useful system views - including those necessary for working out dependencies.

At a minimum you will need the following views:

- admin.v_view_dependency
- admin.v_constraint_dependency
- admin.v_object_dependency

To find all dependents for "TableA", you can query `admin.v_object_dependency` e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM admin.v_object_dependency
WHERE 
   src_schemaname = 'MySchema' AND
   src_objectname = 'TableA';
```

Comment: you may find that views "WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING" are not returned. worth being on the lookout for that. Oh also src_object_name should be src_objectname

Comment: Regarding late-binding views, the tables and columns for those views are only evaluated at query execution time so as far as I'm aware there is no metadata to query to determine dependencies. Therefore as Jon says you probably need to check these separately.